# How to grab changes from Azure DevOps environment associated with current run via api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

We have yaml-based pipeline in Azure DevOps, which is deploying changes to different environments via deployOnce strategy, looking like this:

```
jobs:
  - deployment: deploymentName
    displayName: deploymentDisplayName
    dependsOn: []
    environment: int
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
```

This also creates nice report of changes in Changes tab of Environments in Azure DevOps Pipelines:

[image: view of changes in environment]

What is nice about this view - it is also showing changes, belonging to previous failing deployments as well.

I tried to figure this out, but was not able to actually find correct API call to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I was not able to find any way to collect those changes via one direct API call and built the [script](https://gist.github.com/akuryan/f1218dda7e4741c4acfe1a740a3c79c2) to do it for me

In short, it collects all environments in current Azure DevOps project, filters them according to rules, then selects last successful deployment job in pipeline  basing on name (I have several dependent deployments jobs in each environment) and, finally, tries to get git head deployed to the target environment. Then it will collect all git messages via `git log` and filter them according to the rules, presenting me with comma-separated list of Jira tickets to be deployed in target environment in output variable. This script is executed during build phase and them it's results are consumed by deployment pipeline in deployment phase

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rest API for that - [Environmentdeployment Records - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environmentdeployment-records/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environmentId}/environmentdeploymentrecords?api-version=7.0
```

Comment: It does not lists changes there at all - only results of deployments and builds.

Comment: Oh I missed that you want the changes ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in REST API that can get changes related to a REST API, but there is still a "cheating" way to get this information.

You can open Developer Console (F12 in most browser) and select "Network" tab. Then in Azure DevOps, click on a deployment in the environment. You will get a network trace like this:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_environments/{environment}/runs?environmentExecutionRecordId=xxx&ownerId=xxx&definitionId=xxx&planType=xxx&view=jobshistory&__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

And you may get information you interested in in `ms.vss-environments-web.environment-traceability-changes` and `ms.vss-environments-web.environment-traceability-commits-data-provider`.

Comment: Hmmm... It's a pity that there is no API call for this